# Where can i get a wiki formatting widget for my django application?

Tags: python, django, wiki

Am looking for a wiki formatting widget for my django application, just like the one am using to type this question in stackoverflow?

Comment: a google search with "markup editor" gives you plenty of suggestions.

Comment: There are two different common types: "Wiki formatting" and "Markdown"; the former is what Trac/Wikipedia uses, and the later is what SO uses. All the questions so far seem to point to Markdown, but nobody seems to know how to use *wiki formatting* which is what the OP actually asked for. Also see this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143805/how-do-i-use-wiki-formatting-in-a-django-python-web-application

Comment: If you're looking for Trac wiki formatting, check out this: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1047/

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to this question.  If you're looking for the client-side Javascript WYSIWYG (or WYSIWYM) editor widget, that's unrelated to Django and WMD is a fine choice (though personally I prefer [MarkItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com)).

If you're looking for the server-side (Django) piece of the equation, you might check into [django-markitup](http://www.bitbucket.org/carljm/django-markitup).

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow uses [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) for their editing. This is an editor for the **Markdown** language, which, while not *strictly* wiki markup, is quite close.
An un-obfuscated Stack Overflow-edition version of WMD is available [here](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master).

Comment: if you use the Stack Overflow version, be aware that it was reverse-engineered in violation of the WMD license terms and without the author's permission.

Comment: Although, to be fair, the author was going to give them the unobfuscated version.

Comment: Perhaps.  But the fact is he didn't, and no-one but him has the right to presume what he "would have done" or "meant to do."

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my plugin for Django CMS, which adds Trac wiki syntax (with Trac macro support):

https://bitbucket.org/mitar/cmsplugin-markup-tracwiki