# How do I use Trac wiki formatting in a Django/Python web application?

Tags: python, django, trac

I have a Python web application (Django, specifically). I'm reading in some data from a Trac database (where the descriptions use [wiki formatting](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiFormatting)) and displaying it as HTML. I considered the markdown module, but realised that Trac wiki formatting and markdown are really quite different. Is there a module for Django, or a Python package that supports the wiki formatting that Trac uses?

#### Update:

Looks like I was a little hasty with my vote to close - while the other ticket looks similar, my question is more to do with Trac wiki formatting. Thanks to petantik for the link!

*Similar question:* [Where can i get a wiki formatting widget for my django application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476187/where-can-i-get-a-wiki-formatting-widget-for-my-django-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below links shows a snippet which imports trac markup and makes a django template filter from it

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1047/

Comment: Spot on, thanks. I had to read up on custom template tags (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), and install trac into my site-packages (on my dev pc), but the snippet works a treat!

Comment: Interestingly, this does not add `<br />` tags for new lines where Trac would. All the other formatting works though (bullet points, etc), I wonder why it's not the same for new lines...

Comment: Solved! The snippet does not add `<br />` because `escape_newlines` is `False` by default on the `generate` function. To fix, alter the code like so -- `return mark_safe(HtmlFormatter(env, context, s).generate(escape_newlines=True))`

Comment: Ah, that's great news. I learn so much myself from answering questions on here :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a plugin for Django-CMS which support Trac wiki syntax, with macros and everything else you expect from Trac:

https://bitbucket.org/mitar/cmsplugin-markup-tracwiki