# Django + trac-wiki to html markdown 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, trac, wiki-markup

I am trying to render trac wiki markdown format as html for display on my website. I tried following this other [SO question 'how do i use trac wiki formatting'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143805/how-do-i-use-trac-wiki-formatting-in-a-django-python-web-application), but the [code snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1047/) returns an error when I run it. It should be noted that the question and code are nearly 4 years old. Any idea how I can get this to work?

In my urls.py i simply call the `tracwiki` (from the snippet) view.

**# urls.py**

```
url(r'^$',                       'tracwiki',              name='index'),
```

**# views.py**

```
"""
Usage:

{% load tracwiki %}

{{ object.body|tracwiki }}

# Logic from http://groups.google.com/group/trac-dev/msg/479decac43883dc0
"""

from trac.test import EnvironmentStub, Mock, MockPerm 
from trac.mimeview import Context 
from trac.wiki.formatter import HtmlFormatter 
from trac.web.href import Href

from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import template
register = template.Library()

env = EnvironmentStub() 
req = Mock(href=Href('/'), abs_href=Href('http://www.example.com/'), 
           authname='anonymous', perm=MockPerm(), args={})
context = Context.from_request(req, 'wiki')

@register.filter
def tracwiki(s):
    return mark_safe(HtmlFormatter(env, context, s).generate())
```

Here is the error returned:

```
[01/Apr/2014 18:40:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 60948


AttributeError at /

'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
Django Version:     1.5.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     /mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 30
Python Executable:  /Envs/mysite/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have created a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters), but you have saved it in `views.py`, so django is treating it like a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view). This is wrong - your code doesn't belong in `views.py` and you don't need to add anything to `urls.py`. To elaborate...

With your current configuration, when a request to your site root is picked up by the URLConf (via the `'^$'` pattern you added), django expects the `tracwiki()` function to return a [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) object - because it thinks that this is a view.

However if we look at this `tracwiki()` function, you can see we do not return a `HttpResponse` object via [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) or [`render_to_response()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) etc. Instead we are returning a `SafeText` object which does not have a `.get()` attribute, unlike a `HttpResponse` object, hence the exception when the middleware calls `.get()` on the object we returned.

Instead you need to remove the line you added to your `urls.py`, and use the template filter inside the appropriate HTML template where you want to render this markup. For example

```
{{ some_variable|tracwiki }}
```

If you are unfamiliar with template filters, [here are some built-in filters being used](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference).

You also need to move the `tracwiki()` logic out of the `views.py` file and into a new module inside a new `templatags` directory. Read more about that in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) (but remember you will need to load this new module inside the template before you call the filter)

```
{% load new_filter_module %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for this detailed answer. I've never created or used a custom `templatetag`, so I didn't understand what I was looking at in that code snippet (hence trying to wire it up as a view). In any event the link to the docs and your explanation allowed me to configure it flawlessly. This is fantastic. Basically, I am using the start page from the `tracwiki` as quick-start content on my site's home page. Now I only have to maintain one area and the other is updated. :)

Comment: no problem - i can understand your thought process of putting it into the views.py if you didn't know what a custom template filter was.