# Django - can't get highchart to display data

Tags: django, python-3.x, highcharts

I'm trying to display a chart with help of Highchart by following this solution:

[Passing Django Database Queryset to Highcharts via JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810087/passing-django-database-queryset-to-highcharts-via-json)

But I can't get the data to appear:

[image]

Still new to this and appreciate your help, folks!

---

views.py

```
class ChartData(object):
    def check_valve_data():
        data = {'member_no': []}

        people = Member.objects.all()

        for unit in people:
             data['member_no'].append(unit.member_no)

        return data


 def chartViewHigh(request, chartID='chart_ID', chart_type='column', chart_height=500):
     data = ChartData.check_valve_data()

     chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height, }
     title = {"text": 'Check Member Data'}
     xAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Member'}, "categories": data['member_no']}
     yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Data'}}

     return render(request, 'chart/chartViewHigh.html', {'chartID': chartID, 'chart': chart,
                                                    'title': title, 'xAxis': xAxis, 'yAxis': yAxis})
```

---

chartViewHigh.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles i18n %}

{% block head %}
  <link href="{% static 'css/chart.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

 {% endblock head %}

 {% block main %}

<h1 align="center">Analysis</h1>

{% block content %}
   <div id={{ chartID|safe }} class="chart" style="height:100px; width:100%"></div>
{% endblock %}


{% block extrajs %}
<script>
   var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }};
   var chart = {{ chart|safe }};
   var title = {{ title|safe }};
   var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }};
   var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }};
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(chart_id).highcharts({
       chart: chart,
       title: title,
       xAxis: xAxis,
       yAxis: yAxis,
   });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% endblock main %}
```

---

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns[
    url(r'^chartViewHigh/$', views.chartViewHigh, name='chartViewHigh'),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues:

You need quote marks around the chart ID template variable to make it an HTML attribute:

```
<div id="{{ chartID|safe }}" ...
```

You're not passing in a valid JQuery selector: to select the above div you should use `$("#chart_ID")` (see [JQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)), so with your Django template variable for example:

```
$("#{{ chartID|safe }}")
```

Also the data appears to need a `series` key to render (I haven't used highcharts much but see here - your chart renders when this is added):

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

Also the `ChartData` class doesn't belong in your views.py file - only HTTP request/responses belong there. I recommend working through the official Django tutorial if you haven't already to get an idea of the "Django way" to do things. For example, your `ChartData` method produces a list of member_nos, but you can do this with a single line of code :)

```
Member.objects.values_list('member_no', flat=True)
```