# Build HTML from Django View

Tags: python, html, django

I need to construct the HTML body from a Django view and I cannot find a solution to refer correctly a JPG file ( must say that the HTML is much larger then this, but with other stuff seems that is working for me
):

I've tried this:

```
from django.template import Template
...
html = Template('<IMG SRC="{% static "base/images/course/website-46-2.jpg" %}">')
return HttpResponse( html )
```

And I get this error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 1: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

In Django template I resolve this by loading the static files:

> {% load static %}

How can I do this in Python ( Django View ) ? Or any other suggestion is much appreciated.

I've tried different solution that I have found on this site and others but none seems to work for me.

Django Version: 2.2.1

Comment: {% extends "name" %} ?

Comment: Don't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an engine with the `static` library as a built-in. This makes it available to the template without calling `{% load static %}` first.

```
from django.template import Template, Context, Engine

engine = Engine(builtins=['django.templatetags.static'])
template = engine.from_string('<IMG SRC="{% static "base/images/course/website-46-2.jpg" %}">')
return HttpResponse(template.render(Context()))
```

Comment: With this, I get this error: AttributeError at /course/1/
'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: That's probably something like this (invalid view): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987462/django-safetext-object-has-no-attribute-get/43991530

Comment: Not likely because I have a view like this: course( request, question_id ) and it's working without the suggested code.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using and which line is causing the exception? This works for me on Django 1.11.

Comment: Django 2.2.1, line: \lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py in process_response, line 26

Comment: Can you send settings.py file? Perhaps there is some setting there that I'm missing.

Comment: Ah, I think I know the issue. I didn't realize your function was a view (returning a response), I assumed it was a utility function. I've updated my answer to return a response object instead of plain text. See if that works.

Comment: Oh..I should have known that :) Yes, this works now ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your STATIC_URL in settings.py? You can do this by the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Your image would then be found under `'your_app/static/base/images/course/website-46-2.jpg'`.

Does the folder structure follow this convention?  If not you can set the STATIC_URL to `'/base/'`

Comment: Yes I have that setup, STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: Actually my app is called "base" and my effective path to the image is: "project_name\base\static\base\images\course\website-46-2.jpg"

Comment: Have you tried 
`html = Template('{% load static %}<IMG SRC="{% static "base/images/course/website-46-2.jpg" %}">')`

Comment: Doesn't work either, gives and odd result on the page: '>

Answer (score 0):

```
def startchat(request):
   template=loader.get_template('app1/chatbot.html')
   return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

This function loads the html page into Django.
Before that , we need to import the module

```
from django.template import loader
```